# Getting Unathenticated Error NuxtJs Get request

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js

Am trying to do a simple GET request in NuxtJs using Axios. l have configured my nuxt.config.js like this

```
  axios: {
    proxy: true,
    credentials: true,
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/api/'
  },

  proxy: {
    '/api': { target: 'http://localhost:8000', pathRewrite: {'^/api/v1/': ''} }
  },

  auth: {
    strategies: {
      laravelSanctum: {
        provider: 'laravel/sanctum',
        url: 'http://localhost:8000',
        token: {
          property: 'token',
          global: true,
          required: true,
          type: 'Bearer',
          name: 'Authorization'
        },
        refreshToken: {
          property: 'token',
          data: 'token',
          maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30
        },
        user: {
          property: 'user',
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: '/api/auth/login', method: 'post' },
          user: { url: '/api/user', method: 'get' },
          logout: { url: '/api/auth/logout', method: 'get' },
          refresh: { url: '/api/refresh', method: 'get' }, 
        },
        tokenType: 'Bearer',
        tokenRequired: true,
        cookie: {
          cookie: {
            name: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
          },
        },
      }
    },
    redirect: {
      login: '/',
      logout: '/',
      callback: false,
      home: '/'
    },
    
  },

  router: {
    middleware: 'auth'
  },
```

l have tried alot of methods that were posted here before but no avail. Same issues. l also noticed that when l reload the page. Vuex shows user object empty.

Am using Laravel Sactum, any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Both Nuxt and Laravel in the same repo? What is not working (in the network tab)?

Comment: Not in the same repo, l have them in separate ones.  When l sent a GET request from the nuxtjs project (using a sactum guarded API) it returns an error in the nextwork tab saying "unauthenticated"

Comment: Why do you use a proxy btw? If you have the error, start looking why your backend is not allowing the request. Or is the front-end sending bad info?